# Why nomenclature text is not English when loading additional languages in document class?

Tags: languages, nomenclature

I have troubles in getting the right language in nomenclature. Here is a minimal
example:

```
\documentclass[english,italian]{article}

\usepackage[english,refpage]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

text

\nomenclature{Item}{Any kind of item}

\printnomenclature{}

\end{document}
```

My document is written in English but some of it has also an Italian translation,
hence I load both languages. However by doing so the nomenclature gets Italian text:

[image]

As you may guess *Elenco dei simboli* means *List of symbols* (or *Nomenclature*) and *pagina 1* means
*page 1*. If I load only English they are in English.

I could just redefine the commands to print those texts:

```
\renewcommand*{\nomname}{Nomenclature}
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{, page~#1}
```

but I wondered why they showed up in Italian in first place. Perhaps I am loading the
languages in a wrong way (actually I got this source by exporting from LyX, and then trimmed it to the minimum, so it would be its fault).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Package `nomencl` uses `\ProcessOptions` without star. That means the options
   are processed in the order of declaration and not in order of usage. Option `italian` is declared after option `english`, therefore `italian` is executed last.
2. Even if `nomencl` would be fixed and would use `\ProcessOptions*` with star,
   you are out of luck here, because of the way LaTeX processes its options. If an option
   is used, its code is only executed once. That allows `\newcommand` in option code
   without worrying that the user might call the option twice. Global options are processed
   first and `nomencl` will ignore the local option `english`, because it has seen it
   already as global option.
3. Package `babel` will not help, because package `nomencl` does not support it and
   does not use `babel`'s interface for language dependent strings, e.g.

   ```
   % nomencl:
   \addto\captionsenglish{\def\nomname{Nomenclature}}
   \addto\captionsitalian{\def\nomname{Elenco dei simboli}}

   % document:
   \selectlanguage{english}
   \printnomenclature
   ```

A solution is indeed to define the name macros explicitly. Package `nomencl` defines
these in the code for option `english`:

```
\def\eqdeclaration#1{, see equation\nobreakspace(#1)}%
\def\pagedeclaration#1{, page\nobreakspace#1
\def\nomname{Nomenclature}%
```

Comment: Code in lists needs an extra set of indents :-)